# Function to move file to different folder and change the extension. C#

Tags: c#, pdf, path, aspose

I'm looking for a function to move files from one folder to another and change their extensions. To change the format file I'm using `ASPOSE`.

I think I have trouble with:

```
txt.Save( Path.ChangeExtension( des, fileName, "pdf" ) );
```

It works well when I remove "des" but it saves all the files in the same folder.

This is my code:

```
namespace Change
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string dir = @"C:\Source\";
        string des = @"C:\Destination\";

        string[] docs = Directory.GetFiles( dir, "*.txt" );

        foreach ( string fileName in txts )
        {

            Document txt = new Document( fileName );

            txt.Save( Path.ChangeExtension( des, fileName, "pdf" ) );

        }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: System.IO.Path.ChangeExtension only takes two parameters so your example will not compile.

Answer (score 1):

`Path.ChangeExtension` doesn't take three arguments.You need to change extension first then combine new file name with destination path:

```
var newPath = Path.ChangeExtension(fileName, "pdf");
var savePath = Path.Combine(des, Path.GetFileName(newPath));
txt.Save(savePath);
```